# How to use Jquery to get left side slider like Google or facebook mobile site?

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui

I am looking to get the same effect as seen in Google or Facebook left side navigation slider. I have to get the same effect in my mobile site.. Is there a framework or template to achieve that? [image]

Answer (score 1):

That is called a drawer. This is what a quick search yields:

http://jquer.in/javascript-and-jquery-solutions-for-fantastic-mobile-websites/drawer-slide-menu/

It's oriented for mobile, but it can be useful on desktop too.